# go database/sql can not connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, go

When connecting to mysql database `mysql 5.7`

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:xxx@tcp(localhost:3306)/mydb")
err = db.Ping()
```

Error

```
Error 1130: Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

But when connecting via command line no errors?

```
mysql -u root -pxxx -h localhost
```

Have also connected to phpmyadmin with the same user/pass without issues from localhost

## update

How now tried to connect to mysql 8 and it works. How to connect to mysql 5.7?

In the docs it says it supports mysql 5.6+

Answer (score 0):

Normally using the hostname "localhost" is not 127.0.0.1. It's treated specially, causing MySQL clients to use the UNIX domain socket instead of TCP.

This also applies to GRANT. So if you grant to `myuser@localhost`, it means that user has access only via UNIX socket. If you want a user to be able to connect locally but using TCP, you must grant to `myuser@127.0.0.1` or some other wildcard pattern that covers that IP address.

In a way, `myuser@localhost` and `myuser@127.0.0.1` are really different users. They can even have distinct passwords and distinct privileges.

However, the Go driver for MySQL ignores this convention for some reason known only to its developers. Before trying the connection, the Go driver resolves the hostname in your connection string, so it silently translates "localhost" to 127.0.0.1. For MySQL, this means it's literally connecting to a different user than the one you intended.

To use the UNIX domain socket in the Go mysql driver, read [the documentation](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql):

> For TCP and UDP networks, addresses have the form host[:port]. If port is omitted, the default port will be used. If host is a literal IPv6 address, it must be enclosed in square brackets. The functions net.JoinHostPort and net.SplitHostPort manipulate addresses in this form.
>
> For Unix domain sockets the address is the absolute path to the MySQL-Server-socket, e.g. /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock or /tmp/mysql.sock.

The Go mysql driver has established its own conventions for connection strings.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe there is an error with the sqlx package. Try using the sql package like this:

```
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:xxx@tcp(localhost:3306)/mydb")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).